# Rails - how to update model without required items

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model, passwords

I have a model that contains required and free fields. Between the required items is also item with password.

In the **_form.html.erb** I hid the input with a password, so when the user want to update the form, so he will be update the all items except password => that's what I want. But because the item **password** is require, so I will get an error about bad validations.

I would like to ask you, if exist a good way to do this... I can't find some trick for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's :

`validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create`